# SQL query is overlooking a WHERE condition when filtering information from database

Tags: php, sql

The following section of code is used to to filter data from an html page in real time from an SQL database using ajax. For some reason the condition in the SQL statement ignores the following condition `samples_database.sample_storage != 'discarded'` but it works in the second part of the `else` statement.

```
if(isset($_POST["query"])) {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["query"]);
    $query .= "
    SELECT * FROM samples_database JOIN storage_database on samples_database.storage_location=storage_database.id
    WHERE samples_database.sample_storage != 'discarded'
    AND samples_database.env_sam_id LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR samples_database.c_sam_id LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR samples_database.sample_type LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR storage_database.storage_name LIKE '%".$search."%'
    ORDER BY samples_database.env_sam_id;";
} else {
    $query .= "
    SELECT * FROM samples_database JOIN storage_database on samples_database.storage_location=storage_database.id WHERE sample_storage != 'discarded' ORDER BY samples_database.env_sam_id;";
}
```

Can anybody help me this this silly problem please?

Comment: You really should try to move towards prepared statements as soon as possible. With OOP the MySQLi and PDO extensions are much less error prone.

Comment: There's an order of precedence: `AND` is calculated before `OR`, you probably need parentheses.

Comment: Are you sure it is ignoring that part or are you ignoring operator precedence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an order of precedence: `AND` is calculated before `OR`:

```
if(isset($_POST["query"])) {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["query"]);
    $query .= "
    SELECT * FROM samples_database JOIN storage_database on samples_database.storage_location=storage_database.id
    WHERE samples_database.sample_storage != 'discarded'
    AND (samples_database.env_sam_id LIKE '%".$search."%' OR
         samples_database.c_sam_id LIKE '%".$search."%' OR
         samples_database.sample_type LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
         storage_database.storage_name LIKE '%".$search."%')
    ORDER BY samples_database.env_sam_id;";
} else {
    $query .= "
    SELECT * FROM samples_database JOIN storage_database on samples_database.storage_location=storage_database.id WHERE sample_storage != 'discarded' ORDER BY samples_database.env_sam_id;";
}
```

Comment: Yip, that was the problem! Thank you I will accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

In the else part you have only 1 condition:

```
sample_storage != 'discarded'
```

so it can't be *"ignored"*.
But in the if part you have something like this:

```
A and B or C or D or E...
```

If one of C or D or E... is `true` then the result is `true` and you **think** that `A` is *"ignored"*. 
So make use of parentheses around each part that suits your needs.  
maybe something like this:

```
A and (B or C or D or E...)
```